# Spring-Batch. Need to start a job from failed point, but once started it should be able to execute previous completed steps depending on condition

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a scenario where I have 5 steps in sequence 1->2->3->4->5. Depending on situation and exit status, I re-route from step 4 to step 2. This works fine when the job is started fresh. In a scenario where batch stopped at step 4 and I want to restart the job from step 4, spring batch skips first 3 steps and jumps to step 4 for execution as expected. But the issue comes when from step 4 a condition mets where I want to re-route to step 2, it does not get executed as this job is re-run and this steps was executed in last job.

So my scenario is to skip the steps for first time and start where ever it failed but then should execute previous steps depending on condition.

Please help if any one have come up with situation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you include snippets of your job config file(s)